# Worklight Event Source, what security test

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

Worklight 6.1, testing in WL Studio on a Mac.

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004632/background-work-in-worklight-server) concerning doing background work in a Worklight Server, the accepted answer to which is to use an Event Source.

```
WL.Server.createEventSource(
   {
       name: "housekeepingEventSource",
       poll: {
           interval: 5,
           onPoll: workToBeDone
       },
       securityTest: "eventTest"
   }
);
```

The issue concerns which security test to use. Whatever I try I get this error:

> Adapter deployment failed: Wrapped java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.gen._ (... elisions ...)
>   _chmSecurityService_impl_js_83  cannot be cast to java.lang.String (/integration.js#258)

Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878780/ibm-worklight-6-0-0-1-push-notifications-polling-not-working-in-production-env?rq=1)

I've used this security test:

```
<mobileSecurityTest name="eventTest"> 
        <testUser realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm"/>
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
</mobileSecurityTest>
```

Hints please ...

Comment: This does not look to be related to a security test, but rather to some potentially incorrect code causing this error... did you try backtracking it to find its origin?

Comment: This explicitly happens when I deploy the adapter with that event source entry. If I mis-spell the security test I get a different error. If my security test does not have a device id I get a complaint that the security test must have both user and device entries, if I have the security test as shown I get the error reported. If I remove te event source the adapter does deploy.

Comment: Looks like it's the "poll" item, when the security test is valid we then get the poll activated and that's when the error occurs, thanks.

Comment: And if you replace whichever points to in the poll option to something else (not remove, something else)?

Comment: Right, it was supposed to be in quote marks... it's the little things...

Answer (score 1):

This was a typo in the poll definition. Sequence was that when security test was incorrectly specified the adapter didn't deploy with other error messages. Once I had a valid security test then the poll was activated, and as it wa`s defective we got the above error.

```
   poll: {
       interval: 5,
       onPoll: workToBeDone
   },
```

is wrong, as I should have used a String literal

```
   poll: {
       interval: 5,
       onPoll: 'workToBeDone'
   },
```

which if one reads the error message carefully is exactly what it's telling me ...